# Using a mobile application to enter fields into a website?

Tags: android, ios, web

I have been given a junior project to replicate a web form that allows a user to register details to a database and then have automated e-mails sent to them.

I have just found out that the clients database/website administrator will not allow external access to the DB and so we have hit a bit of a dead end.

The only solution I could conceptualise is to use the pre-existing web-form as a door to the database; use the mobile app to take fields and then pass them through to a website and hit submit.

I feel like you could create a script of some kind to enter information into their relevant fields, and then 'submit', but am not sure if this is possible from a mobile application (iOS/Android/WP8).

Is this possible, or does anyone have any other suggestions?

EDIT:

More details -

There has been no code written by myself as of yet, but the situation is this:
Client PAYS an external company to host their website/database.
Client wants ME to create a mobile application to replicate the job of the website.

The website is simply a form with user input for Name/Phone Number e.t.c. and a submit button.
Once submitted, data is entered to the database.
The client then has a THIRD system which connects to the database and fires off automatic emails (not sure who controls this).

My app was supposed to send information to the database, where the third system would then do it's job working with the new entries gathered my app and the existing form.

The company who provided the website and DB have stated they are not willing to give over control (originally was thinking to write a webservice which connects to the DB to INSERT) and I can understand why, in case I f*** it up and they have to spend time clearing up the mess.

The only two options I can think of are to somehow make this scripty type thing to use the existing website as a portal to the DB, or to ask the client to ask the website administrator if they could at least write a webservice for me to connect to, since it's going to be the same INSERT command they already use.

Thanks!

Comment: Give us more info than the conceptual model, WE NEED CODE :) so to say ..

Comment: @g00dy is right we need some code. My guess is that web form is using some API that you could reuse in your app to submit JSON, but without code hard to say.

Comment: You can use a hidden webView + javascript to fill and submit the form, but I don't think it's a good practice

Comment: I don't have any code at the moment, it's purely conceptual right now.
I'll elaborate further...

Comment: Well, if no code is posted, then you'll only get conceptual answers. Let's not start pasting huge solutions, which are working on principal, but have to be completely re-worked for this case in particular. Give us a basic frame to work on.

Comment: conceptual is fine, I'm not asking for any code to re-work, just a step in the right direction of what I should go off and learn about

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible using a web-form, it should be possible to use a simple post request to send data to the server: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient
hope this helps...

Comment: the only problem with this is, how do I tell the application what fields it needs to enter data into considering I have no control over the website itself?